# How to import a shape file into SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, shapefile

In  the past I have used shape2sql to import shape files into SQL Server.

I tried that route again on a newer Windows 10 box, and nothing seems to happen when trying to use that application.

Any suggestions for either getting shape2sql to work, or alternative ways to upload shape files into SQL Server?

Comment: What do you do with the data once it is in SQL Server? is it mainly the metadata you are concerned with or the actual geometric data (outside of geo-rectifying coordinates) ?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://www.sharpgis.net/page/Shape2SQL

Comment: @ThiagoLoureiro Yes, that is the tool I referenced above. I have used it before, but it seems to do nothing now. I speculate that it's just so old and unmaintained that there is some sort of library that I had on the old Windows 7 box that I don't know how to get on this Windows 10 one.

Comment: Ah, sorry, i didn't noticed the tool name :P but in me quick research nothing new about this, only this old tool..

Comment: @scsimon I need to extract multi-polygons and use them for geospatial intersects queries. The metadata is important, but without the polygons, it's useless to me.

Comment: I did find this tool: http://ogr2gui.ca/ which gives more flexibility as far as types that could be imported into SQL Server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, it turns out that ogr2ogr has the ability to import directly into a SQL Server database now. I created a temporary database and did the following:

- Install ogr2ogr via the GDAL core MSI installer from http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php
- Open a command line to the installed path
- Run the following:

> ogr2ogr -overwrite -f MSSQLSpatial -lco “GEOM_TYPE=geography” -a_srs
>   "EPSG:4326"
>   "MSSQL:server=.;database=temp_import;trusted_connection=yes" "[path to
>   shape file]"

Answer (score 5):

I've managed to import successfully on remote server. Here goes procedure

1. Install [QGIS Desktop 3.10.5](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html)..or whatever version is actual.
2. **How to find out what goes to parameter -a_srs, in my casa that is : `-a_srs "EPSG:3765"`**:

Open QGIS Desktop 3.10.5, open new project and drag-drop your shape file to Layers left sidebar. Right click on that layer and go to Properties. There you will be able to read your -a_srs information.

[image]

3. Run command in `CMD`:

   C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\bin>ogr2ogr -progress -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,yyyy;database=yourDB;UID=yourUse;PWD=yourPassword" "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\ShapeFiles\Name_of_shape_file.shp" -a_srs "EPSG:3765"  -lco PRECISION=NO

Where `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` - IP address of your server
`yyyy` - port number of your server if you are running SQL Server on different port than standard (I think you can omit that in case you are)

**Output**:
        0...10...20...30...40...50...Warning 1: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 664451.64629999956 5053409.8562000087
        60...70...80...90...100 - done.